# Информация по v8

Tags: javascript, v8

где можно почитать доки, статьи по JavaScript машине v8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Хабр 1](http://habrahabr.ru/post/72474/)

[Хабр 2](http://habrahabr.ru/post/72592/)

[Хабр 3](http://habrahabr.ru/post/72765/)

[Хабр 4](http://habrahabr.ru/post/72886/)

[Official docs](https://developers.google.com/v8/)

Comment: Это само собой. Я думал, может на русском есть публикации. Сначала разобрать область, а потом уже на английском читать легче.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, это оно ;)

Answer (score 2):

Вообще [google developers](https://developers.google.com/v8/intro) или вас интересуют какие-то специфические особенности?